# How much experience for hatching a Solstice Dragon?

Tags: dragonvale

In Dragonvale, I was wondering how much experience does the Solstice Dragon give you when you hatch that dragon?

Comment: And just icase u want to know you get 100.000 for selling

Answer (score 2):

According to [the wiki](http://dragonvale.wikia.com/wiki/Solstice_Dragon) they grant 100,000XP when you hatch them.